# Strange Issue With Transparent PNG Files From iOS Photo Library

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm having a very strange issue with transparent PNG files, sourced from the Photos app.

The issue is that I am writing an app that allows the user to bring up an instance of [`UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller), where they select an image, and that image is then added to a [`UIImageView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview) via its [`image`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621069-image) property.

Pretty straightforward, eh? The issue is when the image in the library is a transparent PNG.

For whatever reason, whenever I try to render the image, it always has the background white.

As far as I can tell, the image is stored in the library as a transparent PNG. When I drag it out, and examine it with an image editor, it's fine. Just what I expect.

But when I extract it programmatically, it has a white background. I can't seem to get it to be transparent.

Here's the code that I use to extract the image (It's a picker callback):

```
func imagePickerController(_ inPicker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo inInfo: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    let info = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: inInfo.map { key, value in (key.rawValue, value) })

    guard let image = (info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage.rawValue] as? UIImage ?? info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage.rawValue] as? UIImage)?.resizeThisImage(toNewWidth: Self.maximumImageWidthAndHeightInPixels) else { return }
    
    organization?.icon = image
    
    inPicker.dismiss(animated: true) { DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.imageButton?.image = image
        self?.imageButton?.alpha = 1.0
        self?.imageButton?.tintColor = self?.view.tintColor 
        self?.updateUI()
        }
    }
}
```

It's not actually a `UIButton`. It's a `UIImageView`, with an attached tap recognizer.

The `resizeThisImage()` method is in an extension that I wrote for `UIImage`. It works fine. I've been using it forever:

```
func resizeThisImage(toNewWidth inNewWidth: CGFloat? = nil, toNewHeight inNewHeight: CGFloat? = nil) -> UIImage? {
    guard nil == inNewWidth,
          nil == inNewHeight else {
        var scaleX: CGFloat = (inNewWidth ?? size.width) / size.width
        var scaleY: CGFloat = (inNewHeight ?? size.height) / size.height

        scaleX = nil == inNewWidth ? scaleY : scaleX
        scaleY = nil == inNewHeight ? scaleX : scaleY

        let destinationSize = CGSize(width: size.width * scaleX, height: size.height * scaleY)
        let destinationRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: destinationSize)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(destinationSize, false, 0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }   // This makes sure that we get rid of the offscreen context.
        draw(in: destinationRect, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

In any case, it happens whether or not I use the `resizeThisImage()` method. That's not the issue.

Does anyone have any ideas what may be causing the issue?

**UPDATE:** I implemented @DonMag 's example, and here's what I got:

[image]

Note that the generated "A" is surrounded by white.

I should note that I'm using a classic storyboard UIKit app (no scene stuff). I don't think that should be an issue, but I'm happy to provide my little sample app. I don't think it's worth creating a GH repo for.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code, so I have to wonder if your images *really, truly* have transparency?

Here's a simple example to check. It looks like this when run:

[image]

The code creates Red and Blue image views, with `.contentMode = .center`.

Tapping the "Create" button will generate a `UIImage` using SF Symbol -- green with transparent background, the size of the Red image view -- and save it to Photos in PNG format with transparency.

Tapping the "Load" button will bring up the image picker. Selecting an image (such as the one just created and saved) will load the image and - using your extension - resize it to `80 x 80` and assign it to the `.image` property of the Blue image view.

As you can see, the image loaded from the Photo Picker still has its transparency.

**Your UIImage extension** for resizing

```
extension UIImage {
    func resizeThisImage(toNewWidth inNewWidth: CGFloat? = nil, toNewHeight inNewHeight: CGFloat? = nil) -> UIImage? {
        guard nil == inNewWidth,
              nil == inNewHeight else {
            var scaleX: CGFloat = (inNewWidth ?? size.width) / size.width
            var scaleY: CGFloat = (inNewHeight ?? size.height) / size.height
            
            scaleX = nil == inNewWidth ? scaleY : scaleX
            scaleY = nil == inNewHeight ? scaleX : scaleY
            
            let destinationSize = CGSize(width: size.width * scaleX, height: size.height * scaleY)
            let destinationRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: destinationSize)
            
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(destinationSize, false, 0)
            defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }   // This makes sure that we get rid of the offscreen context.
            draw(in: destinationRect, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1)
            return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```

**UIImage extension to save to Photos** in PNG format with transparency

```
extension UIImage {
    // save to Photos in PNG format with transparency
    func saveToPhotos(completion: @escaping (_ success:Bool) -> ()) {
        if let pngData = self.pngData() {
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({ () -> Void in
                let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
                let options = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
                creationRequest.addResource(with: PHAssetResourceType.photo, data: pngData, options: options)
            }, completionHandler: { (success, error) -> Void in
                if success == false {
                    if let errorString = error?.localizedDescription  {
                        print("Photo could not be saved: \(errorString))")
                    }
                    completion(false)
                } else {
                    print("Photo saved!")
                    completion(true)
                }
            })
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

**Example view controller** uses (essentially) your `func imagePickerController` for loading a photo

```
class TestImageViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    var imgViewA: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var imgViewB: UIImageView = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let vStack = UIStackView()
        vStack.axis = .vertical
        vStack.spacing = 20
        
        let btnStack = UIStackView()
        btnStack.axis = .horizontal
        btnStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        btnStack.spacing = 20
        
        let btnCreate = UIButton()
        let btnLoad = UIButton()

        btnCreate.setTitle("Create", for: [])
        btnLoad.setTitle("Load", for: [])
        
        [btnCreate, btnLoad].forEach { b in
            b.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            b.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
            b.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.75, alpha: 1.0)
            btnStack.addArrangedSubview(b)
        }
        
        vStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(vStack)
        
        [btnStack, imgViewA, imgViewB].forEach { v in
            vStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        [imgViewA, imgViewB].forEach { v in
            v.contentMode = .center
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            vStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            vStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            vStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            
            imgViewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgViewA.widthAnchor),
            imgViewB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgViewB.widthAnchor),
        ])
        
        imgViewA.backgroundColor = .red
        imgViewB.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        btnCreate.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.createAndSave(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnLoad.addTarget(self, action: #selector(importPicture(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    @objc func createAndSave(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let w = imgViewA.frame.width
        
        // create a Green image with transparent background
        if let img = drawSystemImage("a.circle.fill", at: 80, centeredIn: CGSize(width: w, height: w)) {
            imgViewA.image = img
            
            // save it to Photos in PNG format with transparency
            img.saveToPhotos { (success) in
                if success {
                    // image saved to photos
                    print("saved")
                }
                else {
                    // image not saved
                    fatalError("save failed")
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    // create UIImage from SF Symbol system image
    //  at Point Size
    //  centered in CGSize
    // will draw symbol in Green on transparent background
    private func drawSystemImage(_ sysName: String, at pointSize: CGFloat, centeredIn size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        let cfg = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: pointSize)
        guard let img = UIImage(systemName: sysName, withConfiguration: cfg)?.withTintColor(.green, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal) else { return nil }
        let x = (size.width - img.size.width) * 0.5
        let y = (size.height - img.size.height) * 0.5
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
        return renderer.image { context in
            img.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), size: img.size))
        }
    }
    
    @objc func importPicture(_ sender: Any) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.delegate = self
        present(picker, animated: true)
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ inPicker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo inInfo: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
        let info = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: inInfo.map { key, value in (key.rawValue, value) })
        
        guard let image = (info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage.rawValue] as? UIImage ?? info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage.rawValue] as? UIImage)?.resizeThisImage(toNewWidth: 80) else { return }
        
        // organization?.icon = image
        
        inPicker.dismiss(animated: true) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.imgViewB.image = image
                //self?.imageButton?.image = image
                //self?.imageButton?.alpha = 1.0
                //self?.imageButton?.tintColor = self?.view.tintColor
                //self?.updateUI()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an exhaustive response!. I will review everything. I am *pretty* sure that the image is transparent. The way that I test, is to actually drag it out of Photos, and open it with Photoshop (it comes out as ".png", and Photoshop shows checkboxes for the transparent parts). If I break the code out into a separate playground, it works, but I can't reproduce the image picker in a playground.

Comment: Nope. It didn't work for me (see the update, in the question).

Comment: On thing that I should mention, is that my Photos App has iCloud Storage on, as well as Full HDR. I remember a bug report, about three years ago, that said iCloud Photos will interfere with transparency. I will try shutting it off, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yup. It's iCloud Photos. When I turned it off, transparency started working.

Comment: To add insult to injury, if a photo was previously saved in iCloud Photos, it loses its transparency. I have to email the image to my phone, and re-add it to the local library. GRRR...

Comment: Which stinks, because the editor in the picker shows it against a black background. If it is a black template image, then all we see is black.

Comment: I consider this a bug, and have reported it to Apple, along with the project that I created from the @DonMag answer. Since the original discussion that I encountered about this is three years old, I have scant hope that it will be fixed. Now that I know what causes it, I can advise users to avoid it.

Comment: @ChrisMarshall - little searching... yeah, if you save an edited version of the photo, transparency is lost. Also, if "Optimize iPhone Storage" is selected for iCloud Photos, the photo retrieved will not be the original (unless you use code to specifically download the original version).

Comment: What's weird, is that if I drag the photo out of Photos, and open it with Photoshop, it's a transparent PNG. It's only when I read it from the picker that it happens.